# AVAudioRecorder freezes when paused too many times before a stop

Tags: freeze, avaudiorecorder

I have noticed that AVAudioRecorder (iOS) hangs when I pause and resume 8 or more times during the recording.  On the simulator it hangs indefinitely, and on the device I get this errors:

AudioQueueStop posting message to kill mediaserverd

Does anyone know how to prevent this, or is there a workaround?  My problem is that I try to load the file into AVAudioPlayer afterward and the resulting loaded file has no duration (and doesn't play).  The strange thing is that I am able to save the file and later play it just fine.  I'm not certain yet at what point the file is playable, but was hoping if there is a solution to the issue with the recorder, I won't need a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same same problem and I thought i had found a workaround, it seems to work for small recordings, but it still freezes for longer ones:

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(stop) toTarget:myrecorder withObject:nil]

maybe it can work for you if you're lucky, have you filed a bug report? i'll file one now

Comment: @Joey, did you find a solution? I've been searching all over and can't get anything.